# Using SmoothState.js with Wordpress but maintain body classes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, smoothstate.js

Has anyone successfully used SmoothState.js with Wordpress?
Particularly maintaining the classes that are applied to the body tag?

I have applied SmoothState to my Wordpress site but the major problem I have is with the classes on the body tag not updating. I rely on the classes Wordpress adds to the body tag to style different parts of the site. Smoothstate loads/changes page content but I cant get the body tag to update.

Has anyone encountered this same problem before? Could really do with some help.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

The page doesn't really refresh, only everything inside the Smoothstate container is reloaded.

You'll have to move the body class inside the Smoothstate container. You can do this by adding an extra div.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <div id="smoothContainer">
```

To

```
<body>

    <div id="smoothContainer">

        <div <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Don't forget to close it in footer.php!